# AjaxControlToolkit PieChart graphic does not render if only one data value is added

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit, pie-chart

I enter data dynamically from the code behind:

```
PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
{
Category = "1",
Data = count1
});
```

It supposed to reflect the number of ratings from 1-10 by the use of a switch (I didn't show the entire switch because that would be too cumbersome). So in this case, if one person gives a rating of 1, count1 = 1, and I want the pie chart to reflect that, but instead the control remains blank and only has a 1 all the way at the corner, but the legend is still there.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

UPDATE: Here is the switch which goes through the ratings 1 - 10 and adds the amount of that particular rating to the chart:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            if (count1 > 0)
                            {
                                PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
                                {
                                    Category = "1",
                                    Data = count1
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            if (count2 > 0)
                            {
                                PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
                                {
                                    Category = "2",
                                    Data = count2
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (count3 > 0)
                            {
                                PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
                                {
                                    Category = "3",
                                    Data = count3
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (count4 > 0)
                            {
                                PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
                                {
                                    Category = "4",
                                    Data = count4
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            if (count5 > 0)
                            {
                                PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
                                {
                                    Category = "5",
                                    Data = count5
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            if (count6 > 0)
                            {
                                PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
                                {
                                    Category = "6",
                                    Data = count6
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            if (count7 > 0)
                            {
                                PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
                                {
                                    Category = "7",
                                    Data = count7
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            if (count8 > 0)
                            {
                                PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
                                {
                                    Category = "8",
                                    Data = count8
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            if (count9 > 0)
                            {
                                PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
                                {
                                    Category = "9",
                                    Data = count9
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                        case 10:
                            if (count10 > 0)
                            {
                                PieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
                                {
                                    Category = "10",
                                    Data = count10
                                });
                            }
                            break;
                    }
```

Comment: I tried to add values in ACT Sample site [PieChart.aspx](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AjaxControlToolkit.SampleSite/PieChart/PieChart.aspx) Page_Load code-behind and this worked for me exactly like in design time.
Could you provide more details of how do you add these values?

Comment: Well I'd like to highlight that I add values dynamically, not in the client side, and it's only when I want to display a singular value, so the pie chart should only be shown as one solid filled in circle, this is for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: I add this values in server code too. So you mean you add only a **single value** to the PieChart and want to see full circle?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean

Comment: Well, I don't think component creators could imagine such usage of a control. Their code is quite complex and simply draws SVG path with a bunch of parameters, so there is no easy workaround. I think this can be evaluated as a bug, so it is better to post an issue to [CodePlex](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic), so developers will be able to change PieChart internals to handle this situation correctly.

Comment: I will do so now then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything right, but PieChart does not produce valid SVG markup when there is a single value in a series, so you see nothing in result.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well. My fix was just to check for 1 row in the datatable, if so then add another item to the chart with a value of 1, and a label of blank. It's not pretty but in my case, the times there is only 1 item in the chart is quite rare, so I merely explained that when there is only 1 item it may not display correctly. A terrible fix I know but I hope they can fix this in a later release.

```
if(dt.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    pieChart1.PieChartValues.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.PieChartValue
    {
        Category = "",
        Data = 1
    });
}
```